# Multiple forms on one php page not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

So I want to add one more form on the page to insert some data in a database, but it is not working at all. Plus, it broke my first form which worked fine before.
this is the form I want to add:

```
<div class="overlay">
 <div style="margin-top:25%;"> </div>
   <form id="favForm" class="favFormClass" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
         <input type="hidden" name="id_post_fav" value="<?php echo $row['id_post'];?>" />
         <button type="submit" name="fav" style="background:transparent; border:none; cursor:pointer;"> <i class="fa fa-heart" style="font-size:60px;color:red;" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
    <form>
</div>
```

and this is the form from the chat area, that worked fine:

```
<div class="chat-box"></div>

   <form action="#" class="typing-area">
     <input type="text" class="incoming_id" name="incoming_id" value="<?php echo $user_id; ?>" hidden>
     <input type="text" name="message" class="input-field" placeholder="Type a message here..." autocomplete="off">
     <button><i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o"></i></button>
</form>
```

I tried applying different id for each one, but still not working. Also, I can see that the second form has action="#" (the second form is not written by me, that is why it doesn't have button type="submit" or things like that) and if I put action="something1" in the first form, it also applies to the second one... Please help

Comment: For the 2nd form (the one you added), at the end you have  `<form></div>` .. Please change to  `</form></div>`

Comment: I think we need to see the PHP code that processes the forms. And a bit more detail on "not working at all".

Comment: Also as I think @KenLee was saying, the first form in the post is never closed. You have another `<form>` tag where you should have a `</form>`.

Comment: OMG I CAN'T BELIEVE HOW EASY WAS THAT :)))). And I spent a lot of time searching for the problem. BIG BIG THANKS TO YOUR EYES!